# Strategies for postdoc/tenure-track reference letter requests

Tags: postdocs, recommendation-letter, tenure-track

Each individual seeking academic positions has to go through applications several times during each year they are applying. In Math the average might be around a hundred positions and this process is repeated every 2-3 years until the individual finds a permanent academic job.

This makes it annoying for the referee to write hundreds of letters every couple years. I know Mathjobs or euromathsoc may help them to upload once but recently, I see many positions that they require submission of the letters through their own systems.

I wonder if there is a effective strategy to apply for the maximum number of available positions, with minimum amount of annoyance for the referee. One possible approach is maybe submitting the applications only on October 1st, November 1st, December 1st and January 1st  so that the emails get sent to the referee's inbox only four times in a year. Is this functional? or there might be a  better idea?

Comment: You have to pay, but Interfolio offers a service that will collect letters from your referees and send them out and or upload them for you.

Comment: The mathjobs.org website allows a reference letter writer to prepare a single letter and share it with many hiring committees.